# Trigger event when user highlights text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a problem that I recently saw on an e-shop website.

When a user highlights the name of a product, it pops up a little window asking about customer satisfaction and s on, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to use a pseudo class line `:active` or `:focus` to enable this?

Or is there perhaps a custom solution using javascript event listener?

Comment: _"Is there a way to use a pseudo class line :active or :focus to enable this?"_ - no. Both do not apply to text selection, and they apply to whole elements only, not parts of their text content. This will need JavaScript; you'll probably want to start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event

Comment: use `window.getSelection()` or `document.selection.createRange().text` to solve your problem.